# GIT repository migration CONFLICT (rename/rename)

Tags: git, git-merge

I want to migrate a child GIT repo into a parent GIT repo such that the child GIT repo's latest DEVELOP code goes into a subdirectory in parent repo with all the commit history retained.

I followed the steps here - http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2011/09/12/moving-one-git-repo-into-another-as-subdirectory/

and was able to migrate child 3 repo to parent repo without any issues.

But now when I do the same with child 4, i get merge conflicts like:

CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename "src/main/java/com/abc/xyz/persistence/service/TimeServiceKeystoreManagerImpl.java"->"abc-ms/src/main/java/com/abc/ms/customer/persistence/service/TimeServiceKeystoreManagerImpl.java" in branch "HEAD" rename "src/main/java/com/abc/xyz/persistence/service/TimeServiceKeystoreManagerImpl.java"->"ms-uvw/src/main/java/com/abc/xyz/persistence/service/TimeServiceKeystoreManagerImpl.java" in "temp-1/develop"

This is happening for more than 30 files. As can be seen GIT is getting confused with another file which resides in altogether different project (in a separate subdirectory), the only thing common being the file name is same.

After the merge I wanted Child 4 to reside like this:

Parent:

-- Child 1  (Already existing project in a sub directory)

-- Child 2  (Already existing project in a sub directory)

-- Child 3 (Subdirectory)

-- Child 4 (Another Subdirectory)

I have spent more than a day researching on this but unable to find any workaround for this